# How can I properly absolutely position a :before element on an element which is forced to a new line?

Tags: css

I have some text formed of a sequence of `span` elements with some text in each. In front of each span element I want to put a little dot using the :before element (in fact, what I'm trying to do is position a tooltip following [this method](http://cbracco.me/a-simple-css-tooltip/)).

I've noticed a problem when the text is in a fixed-width container. When a span gets forced to a new line because of the width of the container, the :before element gets "left behind".

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ngvyqy0o/

Notice how the :before elements on the "banana" and "pomegranite" spans aren't positioned where the spans actually are, they're positioned where they *would have been* had the spans not been pushed to the next line. Is there a work around?

**This is for use in a Firefox addon, so I'm only interested in Firefox compatibility.**

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a list, a bulleted list. Can you do something with `list-style` on the spans?

Comment: Works for me (On Chrome)

Comment: @MrLister Jeeze, they don't call you Mr Lister for nothing. I don't think I could do that, since I'm trying to simulate a tooltip, in particular I need to put text in there.

Comment: @Alon I edited the post - I specifically need a solution that works in Firefox, since this is for a Firefox addon.

Comment: @JackM I'm not sure what the fiddle has to do with the linked article about tooltips. When did you want to show the tooltip? When the user hovers over the square?

Comment: @MrLister In the tooltip article, the :before element is used as the tooltip. For the sake of simplicity, I'm just using a little blue square in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `inline-block` display to the `span`:

```css
div { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: pink; 
    position: relative;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
span:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    content: " ";
    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>apple</span>
    <span>orange</span>
    <span>banana</span>
    <span>pear</span>
    <span>pomegranate</span>
</div>
```